# Hot Reload for Angular

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript

With Angular, Typescript, and Node, I'm always waiting for a long compile before being able to test any changes.  Is there any concept of a better way to test small changes without the long compile I'm always waiting on? With Flutter & Dart, you are suppose to be able to do a hot reload and see changes right away. Does Angular offer anything in this category?

Thanks in advance for your response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depend's on your pc... but, if you are using Angular 11, you can run with Hot Module Replacement: `ng serve --hmr`

Answer (score 0):

Adding the watch flag '-w' reduced my update times from 90 seconds to 5 seconds.